# Setting Automatic Flush Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Hi I am using the following configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class SpringContextConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public TestsSetup testSetup(){
        return new TestsSetup();
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy dataSource(){
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@AAAA");
        ds.setUsername("AAA");
        ds.setPassword("AAA");
        ds.setDefaultAutoCommit(true);
        TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy tp = new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy();
        tp.setTargetDataSource(ds);
        return tp;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan("setup");
        return lef;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.ORACLE);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }
}
```

> ```
> 2221 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
> 2221 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
> 2221 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC batch size: 15
> 2221 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
> 2221 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Scrollable result sets: enabled
> 2222 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Wrap result sets: disabled
> ```

How can I enable automatic flush.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need it? Spring should handle all necessary transaction and session management itself.

Comment: Where are you setting the hibernate properties?

Answer (score 2):

The property you are looking for is `hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion`

Answer (score -3):

Set autocommit property of hibernate to true as follows

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
```

read more about configuration setting

**[Hibernate Configuration](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_configuration.htm)**

**[3.4. Optional configuration properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional)**

hope this will solve your problem !

Comment: are you kidding? this will disable the possibility to rollback, definitely this will not work in real production environment.      <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion"
    value="true" />